# How to do a try method in ruby

Tags: ruby

I can convert an object to an integer with `to_i`. How can I get it to not convert if the input is not a number?

In python I would do this:

```
h=input("Number: ")
try:
    h=int(h)
except ValueError:
    print("Please enter numbers!")
```

So I tried this in ruby:

```
print "Number: "
h=gets.chomp
try(h.to_i)
    print(h)
end
```

but it prints the input even if I enter letters, so this means I am doing it wrong. What is the correct Ruby way of doing this?

Comment: Your question is very confusing. What does "do a try method" mean? What is a "try method"? We are Ruby programmers, not Python programmers, you should explain Python jargon to us. In Ruby, the term "try method" does not have any particular meaning. What does the Python code you posted do? What is the Ruby code supposed to do? The code you posted doesn't even parse correctly, let alone run. What does it mean that "the input is not number"? You are reading from the console using `gets`, that will *never* be a number, it will *always* be a string.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, if I try your code, it doesn't print the input, it raises a syntax error. Please post the *actual* code you are having trouble with, the code you posted doesn't match with your description of the problem. Also, please provide a *precise* description of the desired behavior, the actual behavior, any error messages and warnings you are getting. Also please provide example inputs and outputs and the precise rules how to get from the inputs to the outputs. Please also provide any edge cases, corner cases, special cases and exceptions of those rules and example …

Comment: … inputs and outputs for those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading [ruby docs for `to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-to_i)

> Returns the result of interpreting leading characters in str as an
>   integer base base (between 2 and 36). Extraneous characters past the
>   end of a valid number are ignored. If there is not a valid number at
>   the start of str, 0 is returned. This method never raises an exception
>   when base is valid.

What you want in your case (to map the Python behavior) is:

```
begin
    Integer(gets)
rescue ArgumentError
    puts "Please enter numbers!"
end
```

Comment: thanks, this worked, i will upvote as soon as i have the rep to upvote

Comment: `Integer` ignores leading and trailing whitespace so you could omit `chomp`